# Why does adding support for std::array in the C++ concept example result in a 'no matching function for call' compilation error?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I am learning C++ concept using the example at [cppreference.com - Constraints and concepts (since C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), which I will reproduce here as:

```
template <typename T> 
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
constexpr double average(std::vector<T> const &vec) {
    const double sum = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.0);        
    return sum / vec.size();
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector sVec { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    assert(average(sVec) == 3); 
}
```

I added the case for std::array:

```
template <typename T, int size>  // add size
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
constexpr double average(const std::array<T, size> &arr) {  // use std::array<T, size> &arr) instead
    const double sum = std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0.0);        
    return sum / arr.size();
}

int main() 
{
    std::array sArr { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    assert(average(sArr) == 3);
}
```

Now there is a compilation error:

```
C:\Users\Cheng\OneDrive\Documents\Proj\HackerRank\Cpp\concept_introduction.cpp:65:19: error: no matching function for call to 'average(std::array<int, 5>&)'
   65 |     assert(average(sArr) == 3);
      |            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Users\Cheng\OneDrive\Documents\Proj\HackerRank\Cpp\concept_introduction.cpp:14:18: note: candidate: 'template<class T>  requires (integral<T>) || (floating_point<T>) constexpr double average(const std::vector<T>&)'
   14 | constexpr double average(const std::vector<T> &vec) {
      |                  ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\Cheng\OneDrive\Documents\Proj\HackerRank\Cpp\concept_introduction.cpp:14:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\Cheng\OneDrive\Documents\Proj\HackerRank\Cpp\concept_introduction.cpp:65:19: note:   'std::array<int, 5>' is not derived from 'const std::vector<T>'
   65 |     assert(average(sArr) == 3);
      |            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Users\Cheng\OneDrive\Documents\Proj\HackerRank\Cpp\concept_introduction.cpp:22:18: note: candidate: 'template<class T, int size>  requires (integral<T>) || (floating_point<T>) constexpr double average(const std::array<T, size>&)'
   22 | constexpr double average(const std::array<T, size> &arr) {
      |                  ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\Cheng\OneDrive\Documents\Proj\HackerRank\Cpp\concept_introduction.cpp:22:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\Cheng\OneDrive\Documents\Proj\HackerRank\Cpp\concept_introduction.cpp:65:19: note:   mismatched types 'int' and 'long long unsigned int'
   65 |     assert(average(sArr) == 3);
      |            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~

Build finished with error(s).
```

Why?

Answer (score 7):

The second template parameter of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a `std::size_t` and not an `int`.

Changing the first line: `template <typename T, int size>`
to: `template <typename T, std::size_t size>`

should fix the issue. Template types **must** match.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler could not resolve this template...

```
template <typename T, int size>  // add size
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
constexpr double average(const std::array<T, size> &arr) {  // use std::array<T, size> &arr) instead
    const double sum = std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0.0);        
    return sum / arr.size();
}
```

because the `size` template parameter to std::array is a size_t, not an int.

Besides this, there is a major issue with your code..

```
template <typename T, size_t size>  // add size
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
constexpr double average(const std::array<T, size> &arr) {  // use std::array<T, size> &arr) instead
    const double sum = std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0.0);        
    return sum / arr.size();

    // What happens when your array/vector is empty?
    // - An integer division by zero, and immediate exit() of your program.
}
```

Other issues...  The goal of C++ templates (and concepts) is to write code that will adapt to many cases, thus reducing the number of lines of code you need to write.   Instead of passing containers to your function, your should consider using something more generic, like iterators.  Example:

```
template <typename ConstIterator>
constexpr double average(ConstIterator first, ConstIterator last)
    requires std::convertible_to<decltype(*first), double>
{
    if (first == last)
        return 0;
    const double sum = std::accumulate(first, last, 0.0);        
    return sum / std::distance(first, last);
}
```

Note the looser requirement using convertible_to<>, this will allow the use not only with any suitable arithmetic types, but also with classes that define `operator double()`.

Comment: *What happens when your array/vector is empty?* Well, since `sum` is a `double`, that would be a `double` division by `0.0`. And in all IEEE conformant hardware, the result is NaN, which makes sense.

Comment: Since we’re using C++20, I would also suggest a range over a pair of iterators.

Comment: @prapin  Sometimes dealing with a lone NAN lost in a sea of numbers ends up being worse than a hard integer divide by zero termination.

Comment: Yes.  That is a good suggestion.  In fact, use range is a better solution for genericity.

Comment: Yeah, ranges are good, but I'm not entirely buying it.  Ranges are all or nothing, which may not always be what you need or want.  Especially in the embedded world, where the data source may not even be stored in a standard container.  A common use for average is to get the average on a portion of the data, excluding extremes, after sorting.  That's just one example.

Comment: `sized_range` and `subrange` exist. Your example is also a perfect use-case of ranges and views.